# facebooksdk cannot get accesstoken swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a simple view controller with two buttons. The first is the official facebook login button I got with

```
let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
```

And by the way, how do I view the implementation of FBSDKLoginButton? I have tried command clicking and I don't see the init function.
Anyway, this button works just fine. I can login, and I'm able to get the accessToken with

```
accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
```

However whenever I make my own login button and I login with

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Custom FB login failed", err ?? "")
                return
            }
        }
```

My current accessToken returns nil. I cannot figure out why it works for the normal button but not for my own. What am I doing wrong?

And to make this more weird, sometimes both buttons do work. It's like 9/10 times it fails but 1/10 times it works when I restart the app.

Edit:
Ok looking online more I see its because I'm trying to get the access token before

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

is called in the app delegate. But that begs the question. Why do I not have to worry about that issue with the original button but I do for the custom button? How do I ensure that the delegate method is called first?

Edit: Now that I put a print statement in my code I see that that method is only being called once anyway. So no that is not the problem.

Edit: Just to be clear, the custom button allows me to get the proper token,but not immediately after I log in. I have to wait some period of time. But I don't know how long to wait.

Final edit: I think I have solved it. I am now putting FBSDKAccessToken.current() inside of the completion handler for facebook login manager. Viola! That seems to be working so far. Not sure why none of the tutorials online had to do that but hopefully it works with no issues.

Comment: what is the result of your if err != nil ?

Comment: The err is always nil. In other words the login is perfectly fine. It's the access token i can't get.

Comment: have you tried this AccessToken.current

Comment: That doesn't exist for me.

Please see my new edit. There is something wrong with when the delegate method is being called.

Comment: tried with this AccessToken.current!.authenticationToken ?

Comment: I don't see an authenticationToken. And I don't have a property called current, it's a method. so FBSDKAccessToken.current()

Answer (score 0):

If error is nil the accessToken is in **FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()**

**Swift 2**

```
if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {

     let accessToken = token.tokenString
     // USE YOUR TOKEN HERE
}
```

Comment: I don't have a "currentAccessToken()".

Comment: currentAccessToken() is for Swift 2

Comment: Sorry I should have indicated I'm on Swift 3

Comment: in Swift 3 is FBSDKAccessToken.current() and, as you wrote, this is != nil in completion handler